# How Can I execute .ELF file on Qemu?

Tags: virtual-machine, elf, qemu, powerpc

I compiled the Linux Kernel and run it successfully on Qemu, but I want to run a non-linux operating system.

I have a file named RTOS.elf, compiled for PowerPC. I'm trying this code, but I can't get any results.

**qemu-system-ppc -M ppce500 -m 512 -kernel RTOS.elf -nographic**

Comment: It's very unlikely that a whole operating system would be an ELF file.

Comment: QEMU's `-kernel` option only supports Linux kernels or [multiboot version 1](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html) ELF format kernels. So if you have a proper ELF file it must have a multiboot 1 compatible header in it within the first 8k of the file and aligned on a 32-bit boundary. If there is no [multiboot version 1 header](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#OS-image-format) present it won't boot.

Comment: Is the only way to run this .elf file add multiboot header to the kernel?

Comment: Correct, you will need to add a Multiboot header to your kernel file.

Comment: Oh, I was basing my comments on your previous question that didn't mention that you are doing this for PPC nor am I sure if there are any patches or specs for such a thing on PPC. I'm not sure if Multiboot ELF works for PPC. The Multiboot spec was originally designed for the x86. I personally don't know, as I target Multiboot to x86 only. It may be on PPC that you can only boot Linux kernels

Comment: Is there a document explaining in which architectures the conditions you have said are valid or not?

Comment: The Multiboot spec I linked in my first comment does say _This specification is primarily targeted at PC, since they are the most common and have the largest variety of operating systems and boot loaders. However, to the extent that certain other architectures may need a boot specification and do not have one already, a variation of this specification, stripped of the x86-specific details, could be adopted for them as well._ . I am not aware of any variations of the Multiboot protocol that became standardized for other architectures, but QEMU's `-kernel` only supports Multiboot on x86

Comment: ppce500 machine accepts plain ELF and u-boot images in `-kernel` parameter. I don't think it's documented, but it's easy to look up in the QEMU code: search for the machine name under hw/ and you'll find machine initialization code. Every machine that supports `-kernel` option handles it somewhere in its init function. E.g. here's where ppce500 does it: https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=hw/ppc/e500.c;h=0d1f41197cf649ed3dfb971728a33f34ecb28690;hb=fdd76fecdde1ad444ff4deb7f1c4f7e4a1ef97d6#l1037

Comment: In general you can start debugging by adding options `-d in_asm,exec -D log` to the QEMU command line that will dump history of code translation and execution to the logfile and then looking at that file.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found such a resource (https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/generic-loader.txt) while my research is ongoing. According to the explanation written here (63);
  
-device loader,file=<file>[,addr=<addr>][,cpu-num=<cpu-num>][,force-raw=<raw>]

Could loading an .elf file with such a use be an alternative for multiboot header?